# How to use the Strings in if statements on document listeners

Tags: java

I honestly don't know how to ask this question so sorry if it doesn't make sense but i will try to explain it here. I am making an app in which the user can enter commands, i want them to be able to type in the first few letters of the word and have the program predict what they want to type, i already have the code to handle that.

```
private final static String[] commands = new String[] {"help", "time", "date", "again", "weather"};

public static void predictiveText() {

        commandField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                if (e.getOffset() + e.getLength() == e.getDocument().getLength())
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            predict(commandField);
                        }
                    });
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            }
        });

    }

    private static void predict(JTextField field) {
        String text = field.getText();

        String prediction = null;

        for (String color : commands) {
            if (color.startsWith(text) && !color.equals(text)) {
                if (prediction != null)
                    return;

                prediction = color;
            }
        }

        if (prediction != null) {
            field.setText(prediction);

            field.setCaretPosition(text.length());
            field.select(text.length(), prediction.length());
        }
    }
```

The only problem is this uses an array to check if the commands match while my program uses if statements to handle the processing of commands.

```
} else if (AssistantFrame.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("card") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("playing card") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("playingcard") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().toLowerCase().contains("pick a card") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().toLowerCase().contains("name a card") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().toLowerCase().contains("choose a card") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().toLowerCase().contains("pick a playing card") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().toLowerCase().contains("name a playing card") || AssistantFrame.getCommand().toLowerCase().contains("choose a playing card"))  {

            MiscAction.generatePlayingCard();
```

Is there any way to get the String that checks if the command has been entered in the if statement to show up in the predictive text. Or is there another way to handle the processing of commands while making it work with the predictive text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Trie data structure, it's faster, and cleaner to code
it's not in Java standard library, but you can implement it fairly easy, the internet is full of examples .

Comment: yes basically it's an implementation, i just wrote a simpler implementation for you, you'll find a link about the details of the Trie data structure . 
[gist link](https://gist.github.com/mehdithe/ea1fd039abcb8ccc2505a7a64e689ed7) this is the link to the gist .